# Difference in precision for autograd.grad() for two different models

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, autograd

I have two NNs implemented with pytorch. They are the same (and initialized with the same weights), except that one has an additional final layer that interpolates the results of the forward method.

Such NN is specified as such:

```
def custom_output(o, x, y):
  minA = [-0.5, 1]
  minB = [0.5, 1]
  XA = (1/2 -1/2 * torch.tanh(1000*(((x - minA[0])**2 + (y - minA[1])**2) - (0.1 + 0.02)**2)))
  XB = (1/2 -1/2 * torch.tanh(1000*(((x - minB[0])**2 + (y - minB[1])**2) - (0.1 + 0.02)**2)))
  q = (1-XA)*((1-XB)* o + (XB))

  return q

class CustomLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, input, x, y):
        # Apply custom function using input, x, and y
        output = custom_output(input, x, y)
        return output


class InterpolatedNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size): #number of initial nodes
      super(InterpolatedNN, self).__init__() #calls the initiation function of the class 

      self.hidden1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 10) # 2 input features (x and y coordinates), 10 hidden units
      self.hidden2 = nn.Linear(10, 20)
      self.output = nn.Linear(20, 1)
      self.interpolation = CustomLayer()

    def forward(self, x, y):
      coordinates = torch.cat((x, y), dim=1)
      
      out = torch.tanh(self.hidden1(coordinates))
      out = torch.tanh(self.hidden2(out))
      out = torch.sigmoid(self.output(out))
      out = self.interpolation(out, x, y)
      return out
```

And the other one as:

```
class TwoLayersNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size): #number of initial nodes
    super(TwoLayersNN, self).__init__() #calls the initiation function of the class 

    self.hidden1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 10) # 2 input features (x and y coordinates), 10 hidden units
    self.hidden2 = nn.Linear(10, 20)
    self.output = nn.Linear(20, 1)

  def forward(self, x, y):
    coordinates = torch.cat((x, y), dim=1)
    
    out = torch.tanh(self.hidden1(coordinates))
    out = torch.tanh(self.hidden2(out))
    out = torch.sigmoid(self.output(out))
    return out
```

Now, when I try to compute the gradient for both outputs (I wanted to check wether the result was the same):

```
x = torch.rand(10, 1).requires_grad_()
y = torch.rand(10, 1).requires_grad_()

torch.manual_seed(1)
m_1 = InterpolatedNN(2)

out = m_1(x, y)
o = custom_output(out, x, y)
grad_x, grad_y = torch.autograd.grad(out.sum(), (x, y), create_graph=True)
print(grad_x)


torch.manual_seed(1)
m_2 = TwoLayersNN(2)
out = m_2(x, y)
grad_x, grad_y = torch.autograd.grad(out.sum(), (x, y), create_graph=True)
print(grad_x)
```

The output is:

```
tensor([[-8.2997e-03],
        [-5.3281e-02],
        [-6.3462e-03],
        [-1.1440e-02],
        [-1.1525e-02],
        [-1.4034e-02],
        [ 8.6983e-06],
        [-1.1623e-02],
        [-9.2993e-03],
        [-1.0333e-02]], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
tensor([[-0.0083],
        [-0.0083],
        [-0.0063],
        [-0.0114],
        [-0.0115],
        [-0.0140],
        [-0.0089],
        [-0.0116],
        [-0.0093],
        [-0.0103]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
```

Why the difference in precision between the two?

Comment: Can you print out the dtype for both tensors?

Comment: It's torch.FloatTensor for both ( print(grad_x.type())

Comment: Hmm, `torch.FloatTensor` corresponds to float32, so both tensors should have the same precision, perhaps its a precision display configuration? Can you try adding `torch.set_printoptions(precision=6)` before printing out the tensors?

Comment: That was my doubt too. By doing as you suggested, the second tensor is [[-0.008300],[-0.008275], [-0.006346],... so it puts more digits, but the numbers are still rounded up. Moreover, the second number seems to be completely different between the two ( [-5.3281e-02], and   [-0.008275],)